# Django exclude insert/select logs

Tags: python, django, logging

Every time I use `get_or_create` or any similar method, a have lots of logs in my terminal.

I don't want to reduce logging level, but I also don't want to recieve these logging messages from Django.

How can I avoid them?
Any corrections in settings.py?

**Update 1**
All these messages come from `utils.py:90 [django.db.backends]`. Should I comment this line in the library? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging configuration is in settings.py.

Here is the documentation with some examples: [Django logging config - examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#examples)

In your case, you have to add something like

```
'loggers': {
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'filters': ['SQLStatementsFilter'],
    },
```

This is *not* the full config and please check the documentation. The idea is to implement a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#id5) that will filter all unwanted log messages only for all classes in the `django.db.backends` module (and submodules).

Comment: Yeah, I know. I said, I don't want to reduce logging level. I want to log INFO and DEBUG. I simply don't want to log django models SELECT/INSERT/any other method.

Comment: Ah. ok. Then you have to implement a special filter. I've updated my answer :)